# Consulta via eloquent en controlador y enviar datos a la vista

Tags: laravel

Chicos como estan, no logro darme una idea para lo siguiente: tengo una tabla materials (nombre_id, etc) una tabla ingreso_materials (que almacena un servicio_id y otros datos) y una tabla det_ingreso_materials( que almacena un ingreso_material_id, el que hace de llave relacional con la tabla ingreso_materials) entonces necesito mostrar en una vista todos los materiales segun el servicio_id (el que esta en la tabla ingreso_materials) pero estoy completamente perdido con las relaciones en los modelos...

Estas son mis tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en los modelos tengo las relaciones asi:
Modelo IngresoMaterial:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo DetIngresoMaterials:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo Servicio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo Material:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el controlador tengo una funcion que recibe un parametro ($id) que es el servicio_id para poder traer los materiales ingresados a ese servicio:

```
public function mostrar_materiales($id){
//aca el codigo para traer los materiales y enviarlos a la vista
}
```

Algo que me este pasando por alto? la verdad solo puedo obtener el detalle de un ingreso pero no se como proceder con lo demas (obtener todos los materiales de los ingresos asociados a un servicio)

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacerlo como dice la documentación oficial:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

puedes hacerlo mediante pivot o como yo lo hago:

```
$pacientes = Paciente::with(['compania'])->paginate(10);
```

tengo unos pacientes que están asociados a compañías. Por medio de with y el nombre que se le establece a la relación:

```
public function sesiones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sesion::class, 'paciente'); 
    }
```

puedo obtener los datos de la compañía asociada.

Entiendo que tengas dudas con las relaciones y los modelos, también para mi es de lo más complicado si no lo más. Nunca me aclaro tampoco. Pero espero haberte guiado un poco.